# How to remap :bn and :bp

Tags: vimrc

I have these remaps for buffer switching in my .vimrc

```
let mapleader = ' '
nnoremap <leader>bk :bw<CR>
nnoremap <leader>bn :bn<CR>
nnoremap <leader>bp :bp<CR>
```

If I run ":so%" to reload the config, they work as expected. If I restart vim, only the remap for :bw persists. The maps for :bn and :bp fail to switch buffers, and instead move me around the file. It appears to be doing a search and iterating the results on the 'n' keystroke instead of switching buffers.

Comment: What does `:verbose map <Leader>bn` show? It sounds like it might be remapped by a plugin or something else?

Comment: not quite, turns out it was loading the wrong config, which makes sense why it worked when I loaded it manually. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was loading the wrong config, which makes sense why it worked when I loaded it manually.